# Real time chart (SVG) + AJAX/Javascript/Jquery + StdOut + Python + I dont really know myself

Tags: python, ajax, svg, cgi, charts

I am not sure how to accurately describe my problem , and right now i have a total mess in my head , so please deal with it and correct me if i am wrong , and i will be for sure.

**MAIN GOAL:**

**Is to built a real time line chart  , which updates itself without web page reloading based on data , which comes from stdout .  So it basically must be python script  , which gets every second value , and based on this values continues to draw line in a line chart .**

1) Well basic tags in my head right now are :  Javascript / AJAX , cgi , python http web server , SVG (Vector graphics).

So basically the **biggest problem** , which i dont understand is how to continuesly transfer stdout values to the webpage .  Should i write my own python http web server , somehow pass values and with javascript or ajax + SVG draw the chart .

Or writing a http web server is a stupid idea and i can somehow make it work without it ?

Any other suggestions , or pointing me to some tutorials or arcticles are welcome . Because right now i am very confused  , especially on the part of continuesly passing values to webpage.

Thx in advance. Hope you will be able to point me somewhere =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use JavaScript to render the chart, for example using a library such as [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). Then, you can use AJAX to make an HTTP request back to a web server to get your data.

Depending upon your needs, you could just keep making these calls periodically to get new data. Or you could look into using a more efficient technique such as [web sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets), [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), etc.

Comment: As for the server-side itself, a small python server made with Twisted or some other small framework would help you provide the values you need.

Comment: Thx. i guess comet is exactly what i need. Didn;t even know that thing like this exists .

Answer (score 4):

Highcharts are nice for a static data or for data updated at max 1000ms speed. Try changing update rate to 100ms - it looks like crap.

I would recommend [Smoothie Charts](http://smoothiecharts.org/). Fits perfectly for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Smoothie - it fit my needs perfectly! And you are right about highcharts - wish I'd read your answer 6 months ago :p

Answer (score 2):

Also check the real-time updates possibilities of Flot: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/

I use a database as buffer, so no need for Comet or other push-techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JavaScript to create or manipulate an SVG document, with AJAX requests polling the server and getting data back.